# GCC preprocessor with -E and save in file named x

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

How i could save le preprocessor in output file with specific name as x or y ?

I tried the command line :

```
gcc -E -o pgcd.c x.o
```

But it don't seem being the solution.

ps: the file doesn't exist before the compilation, i just would save the preprocessor in a file with the name i defined.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `gcc -E pgcd.c -o x.o`?

Comment: On the face of it, `gcc` might have ignored the `x.o` file (not a C source file), mercifully saving your `pgcd.c` source file from being obliterated.  (Do you have a backup in your VCS — version control system — yet?)  The `-o` option takes a file name argument which is overwritten by the output from whatever it is doing.  Be cautious!

Comment: i tried {gcc -E pgcd.c -o x} without .o extension, do you think it's work , because an x file was created, so pgcd.c shouldn't have been overwritten ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gcc -E file.c
```

will preprocess `file.c` and write the preprocessed source code to the
standard output (console). So to save the preprocessed output, redirect
the standard output to a file of your choice:

```
gcc -E file.c > somefile
```

It is a bad idea for *somefile* to have an `.o` extension. GCC and other
tools interpret the `.o` extension as meaning that the file contains object
code, as output by compilation. Preprocessing `file.c` does not produce
object code. It just produces preprocessed source code, which you might later compile.

The conventional file extension for preprocessed C source code is `.i`
(`.ii` for preprocessed C++ source code). Therefore

```
gcc -E file.c > file.i
```

is the appropriate choice.

You will discover that `file.i` contains preprocessor line-markers, e.g.

```
# 1 "file.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "file.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
...
...
```

If you don't want these line-markers to appear in the output, add the `-P`
option:

```
gcc -E -P file.c > file.i
```

Comment: thank you very much for you meaningful answer !
If i don't use the .i extension , what will be the difference  ?

Comment: There'll be no difference in the output but as I said, using `.o` extension will mislead people and tools, esp. compilers and linkers, to believe that the file is an object-code file.

Comment: @ChrysBltr I would add that GCC itself will recognise an `.i` file as preprocessed C code and compile such an input file as C without special prompting, skipping the unnecessary preprocessing phase.

Answer (score 0):

The GCC `-save-temps` flag can also be used to save the processed file in *.i files (although this differs from `-E` in that compilation of the files are not halted after the pre-processor stage).